# Monitor only works when I reboot Windows

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

I have a problem with my computer: I switch it on, I know it's running but I can't see nothing on the screen. As soon as my keyboard lights are on, I know Windows has already started, and I can reboot it. When I do this, the screen works normally.

By doing some researching, I found out that if I switch the monitor with the default graphic card (the one in the motherboard) it works well, but connecting it to the graphic card (Nvidia GeForce 9500 GT) is when I have to reboot it.

Anyone knows any solution?

Windows 7 Ultimate 64bits

Comment: What fixes have you tried so far?

Comment: Reset the BIOS, Reset the Nvidia Configuration Panel and Graphic Card configuration, and I cleaned the inside of the computer